my webApplication post method with dynamic parameter return 405 not allowed
I have controller inherit from Controller
with post method take dynamic parameter when i try to call it from postman it always return not allowed when I try to change the type to get to check the route it return unsupported media type other wise I have another controller with same project and it working fine with post method with dynamic parameter
I add Content-Type to application/json with post man
aim making sure that my url is correct
add request body to row in postman
[HttpPost]
[Route( "/call_back")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> CallBack([FromBody] dynamic dynamic)
{

} 

this sample from dynamic request
{
    "obj": {
        "id": "1",
        "success": true,
        "amount_cents": 16.0,
        "order": {
            "id": "231395979"
        },
        "currency": "sr"
    }
}

I add Content-Type to application/json with post man
aim making sure that my url is correct
add request body to row in postman

What kind of data you are sending within the request when saying dynamic? Could you please share that as well?

@MdFaridUddinKiron i add it

So the properties are fixed or which format would continuously changes?

can you add your postman screenshot here?

Would it not make more sense to let the type be JsonElement? Or you are accepting other things than json?

I am not sure how have you sent the request from Postman which causing 405. But I haven't get that error and getting the correct string in dynamic parameter. I think your request format need to check in postman. You should sent as request body by selecting raw and datatype as json. You could check here. Also I got this output

Hi @Huda, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.

This is probably because of the variable name and data type you are sending. You might need to create a variable inside a Model that has dynamic data type and the variable name not being dynamic.
Create a Model called DynamicDataModel
Create a variable inside the model called DynamicData
and use the Model like this
[HttpPost]
[Route( "/call_back")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> CallBack([FromBody] DynamicDataModel dynamic)
{

} 


It is working for me in another endpoint in the same project it take dynamic object and it working fine

When you are saying working for another project does the project version is same? You are getting null element becuase of model binding. If you want to make this json string work in that case you need to change couple of things in controller, if you want I can give you the solution. But I need to know after receiving the data what would be your next step? Will you bind the json object into model? Or what?


I have controller inherit from Controller . With post method take
dynamic parameter when i try to call it from postman it always return
not allowed when I try to change the type to get to check the route it
return unsupported media type other wise I have another controller
with same project and it working fine with post method with dynamic
parameter

Well, based on your description and shared code snippet I have tried to reproduce your issue.
As per your method signature it seems, you reuqest from postman should be sent as Body in postman because your method parameter requires [FromBody]
Which means it should get values from the request body.
Another considering measure is, your request body seems json. So in order to send json request body you should select raw in postman then select data type as json.
So your request should be sent as following:

I have used the controller as following:
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
   
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/call_back")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CallBack([FromBody] dynamic dynamic)
    {
        return Ok(dynamic);
    }
    
}

Output:


Note: Within the controller return type I noticed that, you have used StatusCodeResult as return type. However, in order to test the scenario, I have used simple IActionResult. If you have any specific reason so use StatusCodeResult in that case handle your logic inside the controller action.
